# Html.DropDownList AutoMapper problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, automapper

I am receiving this error:

> The ViewData item that has the key 'DepartmentId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

with the following set up.  I am not sure how to resolve it.  The error is happening in the Model View code.  This line: public void MapTo(Person domainModel).  I am using AutoMapper to map ViewModel back to DomainModel (reversing the initial mapping of DomainModel to ViewModel).

Domain model (using LINQ to SQL, so this is a partial class):

```
public partial class Person { }

// Validation rules
public class Person_Validation
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public object PersonId { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public object DepartmentId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Employee Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Employee Name cannot be more than 50 characters")]
    public object Name { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]        
    public object Active { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public object DateAdded { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public object DateDeleted { get; set; }

    public object Department { get; set; }     
}
```

This is my Model View:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{       
    public object PersonId { get; set; }

    public object DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public object Name { get; set; }

    public object Active { get; set; }

    public object DateAdded { get; set; }

    public object DateDeleted { get; set; }    

    public object DepartmentName { get; set; }

    //helper method
    public void MapTo(Person domainModel)
    {
        Mapper.Map(this, domainModel);
    }
}
```

Controller Class Code:

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult Edit(PersonViewModel viewModel)
{
    var domainModel = new Person();                                       
    try                    
    {                      
        viewModel.MapTo(domainModel);
        UpdateModel(domainModel);
        _personRepository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Person");
    }                      
    catch                  
    {                      
        return View(viewModel);
    }                      
}
```

And my View HTML code:

```
<div class="editor-field">                
<%: Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["DepartmentList"])%>                                     
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not really following the best practices of developing a mvc application.

About the error:
the Html.DropDownList looks for Data of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the model but it finds an `int` instead (`DepartmentId`)

your ViewModel should not have the MapTo method, it breaks the single responsibility principle

in your action method you don't do any server side validation like:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   //rebuild the viewmodel and return the view
}
```

catching everything in the action is also not necessary (and bad)
you do this in `Global.asax Application_Error` instead

attributes like HiddenInput, ScaffoldColumn, Validation and anything else UI related should be on you ViewModel not in your domain model

---

for a good sample of using **viewmodels & validation & mapping** between **entity <-> viewmodel** I recommend you to look at the Samples solution from [**here**](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/releases/view/50411)

I did this sample and it's main purpose is to demonstrate the usage of [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) (mapping technology)